# Save darkmode state html / css / js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need to know how I could possibly save the state of the darkmode?
I got this js code right here:

```
$('#switch').on('click', () => {
  if ($('#switch').prop('checked')) {
    $('body').addClass('dark');
    $('main').addClass('darklight');
    $('footer').addClass('darklight');
    $('.topnav').addClass('darklight');
    $('.lightm').addClass('darklight');
    $('section').addClass('darklight');
    $('button').addClass('button');
    $('.links').addClass('llinks');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('dark');
    $('body').addClass('light');
    $('main').removeClass('darklight');
    $('main').addClass('light');
    $('footer').removeClass('darklight');
    $('footer').addClass('light');
    $('.topnav').removeClass('darklight');
    $('.topnav').addClass('light');
    $('.lightm').removeClass('darklight');
    $('.lightm').addClass('light');
    $('section').removeClass('darklight');
    $('section').addClass('light');
    $('button').removeClass('button');
    $('button').addClass('dbutton');
    $('.links').removeClass('llinks');
    $('.links').addClass('dlinks');
  }
})
```

Here is the code in Codepen with the html and css things:

https://codepen.io/TRGYT/pen/eYmNBPo

Does anyone have idea on how to achieve this? And can this darkmode state also be saved for other sites I created?

Please find the site here:

https://15min.netlify.com

Sorry in advance for the bad code, I'm a beginner...

Comment: You can save the `darkMode` state in a storage and load the state when the page is loaded. Can be simply from localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or from a remote storage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that wored. The one answer I got helped me understand it, but I was too lazy to implement it. But still thank you!

```
function activateDarkMode() {
  $('body').addClass('dark').removeClass('light');
  $('main').addClass('darklight').removeClass('light');
  $('footer').addClass('darklight').removeClass('light');
  $('.topnav').addClass('darklight').removeClass('light');
  $('.lightm').addClass('darklight').removeClass('light');
  $('section').addClass('darklight').removeClass('light');
  $('button').addClass('button').removeClass('button');
  $('.links').addClass('llinks').removeClass('dlinks');
}

function deactivateDarkMode() {
  $('body').removeClass('dark').addClass('light');
  $('main').removeClass('darklight').addClass('light');
  $('footer').removeClass('darklight').addClass('light');
  $('.topnav').removeClass('darklight').addClass('light');
  $('.lightm').removeClass('darklight').addClass('light');
  $('section').removeClass('darklight').addClass('light');
  $('button').removeClass('button').addClass('dbutton');
  $('.links').removeClass('llinks').addClass('dlinks');
}

$('#switch').on('click', () => {
  if ($('#switch').prop('checked')) {
    activateDarkMode();
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", "enabled")
  } else {
    deactivateDarkMode();
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", "disabled")
  }
});

let mode;
mode = localStorage.getItem("darkmode");

if (mode == 'enabled') {
  activateDarkMode();
  $('#switch').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
```

All I did was putting the `addClass` and `removeClass` into a `function`. He also added the `localStorage` and let the localStorage be in a variable called `mode`. After I created these things, I put them into an `if` to check if the darkmode is turned on or not.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of coding. Before we get to the problem, it will be of some use to you to get to grips with the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). Your code (20 or so lines) could easily be abbreviated to just four. For example:

```
$("#switch").on("click", () => {
  $("body").toggleClass("dark"));
  // Local storage. Will get to this later
});
```

You could then change your CSS to respond to whether or not the `body` tag has the `dark` class. Much cleaner.

---

As for saving the state of the dark mode: use `window.localStorage` like so:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
  const darkMode = window.localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
  if (darkMode) {
    $("body").addClass("dark");
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("dark");
  }
}
```